# How to Uninstall Python3.7.3 using cmd?

Tags: python, uninstall, python3

How to Uninstall Python3.7.3 using cmd ?
i tried using cmd: Msiexec /uninstall C:\Python37\python.exe
But it gives me below error: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeTHV.png)

how do i uninstall it ?

Comment: Try, if your are using Windows, __c:\users\%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python__ folder. You might have an uninstaller there, it should have an option to fix or remove the current installation of the Python software. __PathToPython.exe /uninstall /quiet__ See this page https://bugs.python.org/issue36557

Comment: The folder is empty. Can i Get the uninstall file from anywhere ?

Comment: @user1154462 - [Yes](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-373/).  Have you tried just installing it then removing Python 3.7.3?

Comment: yes, manually using control panel i'm able to do... but I want to do using cmd